# Can anybody pls convert this javascript code to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function checkData(id)
        {
            document.frmAddProduct.hidActionId.value = id;

            document.frmAddProduct.submit();

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: @Felix - I was about to ask the same thing :D

Comment: I think he may be going for the http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure badge

Comment: @Felix: Coz im not totally familiar with pure JS, @Steve: I've no idea about badges :P

Comment: In that case you are not totally familiar with jQuery either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function checkData(id) {
    $("#hidActionId").val(id);
    $("#frmAddProduct").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkData(id) {
   $("#hidActionId").val(id);
   $("#frmAddProduct").submit();
}
```

Profit!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkData(id)
{
 $('#hidActionId').val(id);
 $('#frmAddProduct').sumbit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Ardman: why did you edit my answer?